# кривой редирект в firefox через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, firefox, redirect

На сайте есть две странички с фотками, условно:

```
site.com/photo1.php
```

и

```
site.com/photo2.php
```

Обе страницы редиректятся через htaccess в чпу следующим образом:

`site.com/photo.php?date=180322&name=event`

преобразуется в

`site.com/photo/180322/event/`

Вот два фрагмента из `htaccess`. Первый неверно редактируется в `firefox`, хотя фрагменты полностью одинаковые. в хроме работает всё как положено.

```
# photo1.php - редирект не работает в FF, но работает в хроме
RewriteRule ^photo1/([0-9]{6})/([a-z]+)/?$ /photo1.php?date=$1&name=$2&norec [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=([0-9]{6})&name=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^photo1.php$ /photo1/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]

# photo2.php - редирект работает в FF и хроме
RewriteRule ^photo2/([0-9]{6})/([a-z]+)/?$ /photo2.php?date=$1&name=$2&norec [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=([0-9]{6})&name=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^photo2.php$ /photo2/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

`Firefox` в первом варианте выдаёт такую переадресацию (в адресной строке):

```
site.com/photo1/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/
```

что можно сделать? как поправить `htaccesss`?

Comment: Очистите кэш фаерфокса, относящийся к этому сайту. И никогда не пишите R=301 во время отладки редиректов.

Comment: почистил кэш, убрал с htaccess запись [L,R=301] - не помогло. то же самое - site.com/photo1/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/

Comment: В фаерфоксе: Ctrl+Shift+i, на закладке Network (если не ошибаюсь) включить чекбокс «Disable cache” и еще раз отправить запрос (например, Ctrl+F5)

Comment: ухты! о чудо, не ожидал, но помогло: Инструменты - Настройки - Дополнительно - Сеть - Кеширование веб-содержимого. Поставил галочку "отключить автоматическое управление кэшем" и полностью очистил весь кэш. Хотя я думал, что ctrl+F5 это и есть очистка кэша. Спасибо. ВОПРОС РЕШЁН! :)

Answer (score 0):

спасибо пользователю [defrag](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/278091/defrag).
решение оказалось в **очистке кэша** следующим образом:

в **firefox**: Инструменты - Настройки - Дополнительно - Сеть - Кеширование веб-содержимого. **Поставил галочку "отключить автоматическое управление кэшем"** и полностью очистил весь кэш.
После этого перешёл на нужную страницу и обновил кнопками ctrl+f5 - редирект стал отображаться верно.